# Filter keys of map1 based on filtering criteria in map 2 and filtering info for each item in map 3 using java8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have 3 maps and they are setup as follows:-

```
  //Map1 
  Map<CatalogCd, Set<ItemUID>> availableItems
  //Map2 
  Map<CatalogCd, FilteringPreferences> filteringPrefs
  //Map3 
  Map<ItemUID, ItemInformation> itemDetailInformation
```

What I am trying to do is ,

go through the availableItems, and then see if the ItemInformation for a given ItemUID, matches with the preferences ( by basically doing some kind of predicate check).

As you can see the first two maps have the same keys, the filteringPrefs for the same key apply to the entire set of that catalogcd key, any object that does not qualify as per the predicates setup in Preferences , should be removed from the resulting set of itemuids.

I am interested in doing the java 8 stream, map, filter way of making this look better rather than traditional for loop over one map and then manually removing or adding items to a new result map.

This is the traditional for-loop non-java-8 style of code I got.

```
public Map<CatalogCd, Set<ItemUID>> filterResponse(Map<CatalogCd, Set<ItemUID>> availableItems,  Map<CatalogCd, FilteringPreferences> filteringPrefs, Map<ItemUID, ItemInformation> itemDetailInformation)
{
    Map<CatalogCd, Set<ItemUID>> resultingFilteredItemsMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(Map.Entry<CatalogCd,FilteringPreferences> catalogCdEntry : filteringPrefs.entrySet()){
    CatalogCd catalogCdInRequest = catalogCdEntry.getKey();
    EnumSet<PrefA> prefA = catalogCdEntry.getValue().getSupportedPrefAs();

    //get set of items for this catalogcd, loop over each itemuid, check from itemDetailInformation map
    //to see if that itemuid's enumset has intersection with the enumset in request's preference.
    Set<ItemUID> itemsForThisCatalogCd = availableItems.get(catalogCdInRequest);
    for(ItemUID item:itemsForThisCatalogCd){
        EnumSet<PrefA> enumSetFromItemInfo = itemDetailInformation.get(item).getPrefAs();
        enumSetFromItemInfo.retainAll(prefA);
        if(!enumSetFromItemInfo.isEmpty()){
            if(resultingFilteredItemsMap.get(catalogCdInRequest)!=null){
                Set<ItemUID> items = resultingFilteredItemsMap.get(catalogCdInRequest);
                items.add(item);
                resultingFilteredItemsMap.put(catalogCdInRequest, items);
            }else{
                resultingFilteredItemsMap.put(catalogCdInRequest, Sets.newHashSet(item));
              }
           }
        }
    }
   return resultingFilteredItemsMap;
}
```

What I have tried so far is this:-

```
availableItems
    .entrySet() 
    .stream() 
    .filter(x- >predicateFilterFactory.createPredicateFilter(filteringPref.get(x.getKey()))) 
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(x->x.getKey(),x->x.getValue));
```

but this says Predicate cannot be converted to boolean Also, I dont know how to rope-in the actual content map into this.
Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried this `availableItems
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(x->predicateFilterFactory.createPredicateFilter(filteringPref.get(x.getKey())))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(x->x.getKey(),x->x.getValue));` but this says `Predicate cannot be converted to boolean` Also, I dont know how to rope-in the actual content map into this.

Comment: don't put that here put it in the main post

Comment: okay, updated question with that.

Comment: What does the predicateFilterFactory::createPredicateFilter method do? And whats the value for searchFilterTypeInRequestForThisCatalogCd?

Comment: Those are just my guice assisted factory methods, they instantiate the filter class with the object of prefA. Also, updated code , had missed renaming the objects correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public Map<CatalogCd, Set<ItemUID>> filterResponse(Map<CatalogCd, Set<ItemUID>> availableItems,
        Map<CatalogCd, FilteringPreferences> filteringPrefs, Map<ItemUID, ItemInformation> itemDetailInformation) {
    Map<CatalogCd, Set<ItemUID>> resultingFilteredItemsMap = new HashMap<>();
    filteringPrefs.forEach((key, value) -> giveSuitableName(availableItems, itemDetailInformation,
            resultingFilteredItemsMap, key, value));
    return resultingFilteredItemsMap;
}

private void giveSuitableName(Map<CatalogCd, Set<ItemUID>> availableItems,
        Map<ItemUID, ItemInformation> itemDetailInformation, Map<CatalogCd, Set<ItemUID>> resultingFilteredItemsMap,
        CatalogCd catalogCdInRequest, FilteringPreferences filteringPreferences) {
    EnumSet<PrefA> prefA = filteringPreferences.getSupportedPrefAs();

    // get set of items for this catalogcd, loop over each itemuid, check from
    // itemDetailInformation map
    // to see if that itemuid's enumset has intersection with the enumset in
    // request's preference.
    availableItems.get(catalogCdInRequest).stream()
            .map(ai -> collectAndAddItems(itemDetailInformation, resultingFilteredItemsMap, catalogCdInRequest,
                    prefA, ai))
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).forEach(fs -> resultingFilteredItemsMap.put(catalogCdInRequest, fs));
}

private Set<ItemUID> collectAndAddItems(Map<ItemUID, ItemInformation> itemDetailInformation,
        Map<CatalogCd, Set<ItemUID>> resultingFilteredItemsMap, CatalogCd catalogCdInRequest, EnumSet<PrefA> prefA,
        ItemUID item) {
    EnumSet<PrefA> enumSetFromItemInfo = itemDetailInformation.get(item).getPrefAs();
    enumSetFromItemInfo.retainAll(prefA);
    Set<ItemUID> items = new HashSet<>();
    if (!enumSetFromItemInfo.isEmpty()) {
        if (resultingFilteredItemsMap.get(catalogCdInRequest) != null) {
            items = resultingFilteredItemsMap.get(catalogCdInRequest);
            items.add(item);
        } else {
            items = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(item));
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

Comment: Err , let me try , but i dont see how my predicate comes into picture with either of those solutions.

Answer (score 2):

This method should solve your issue:

```
public static Map<CatalogCd, Set<ItemUID>> filterResponse(Map<CatalogCd, Set<ItemUID>> availableItems, 
            Map<CatalogCd, FilteringPreferences> filteringPrefs, Map<ItemUID, ItemInformation> itemDetailInformation) {
    return filteringPrefs.entrySet().stream()
            .flatMap(e -> availableItems.getOrDefault(e.getKey(), Collections.emptySet())
                    .stream().map(item -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e, item)))
            .filter(e -> itemDetailInformation.get(e.getValue()).getPrefAs().stream()
                    .anyMatch(e.getKey().getValue().getSupportedPrefAs()::contains))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey().getKey(), Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toSet())));
}
```

But I do not think that this will make your code more readable. Hope this helps.

You can just add the `filter()` statement you already have directly after the `flatMap()` or before the `collect()`.

---

**EDIT:** Here is a little explanation:

1. the `flatMap()` joins the `availableItems` based on the keys of `filteringPrefs`. This is the first part in your first loop:

```
CatalogCd catalogCdInRequest = catalogCdEntry.getKey();
EnumSet<PrefA> prefA = catalogCdEntry.getValue().getSupportedPrefAs();
Set<ItemUID> itemsForThisCatalogCd = availableItems.get(catalogCdInRequest);
for (ItemUID item: itemsForThisCatalogCd) {
    // ...
}
```

2. The `filter()` part looks for items which have any pref available in supported `itemDetailInformation`. This is the `retainAll()` and not empty part of your code.

```
EnumSet<PrefA> enumSetFromItemInfo = itemDetailInformation.get(item).getPrefAs();
enumSetFromItemInfo.retainAll(prefA);
if (!enumSetFromItemInfo.isEmpty()) {
    // ...
}
```

3. The `collect()` step joins all items back to a `Map<CatalogCd, Set<ItemUID>>`, using the original key of `filteringPrefs` and the value of `availableItems`. This is the last part of your code:

```
if (resultingFilteredItemsMap.get(catalogCdInRequest) != null) {
    items = resultingFilteredItemsMap.get(catalogCdInRequest);
    items.add(item);
} else {
    items = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(item));
}
```

Comment: @Rohit Yes that would help. For my tests it worked and it seems correct for me.

Comment: Seems correct in my test as well. But debugging this would be nightmare IMO.

Comment: How do I plug my predicate in this ?

Comment: @MithunS which predicate? This method should do the same as the method you shared.

Comment: My filter was taking in an object of a predicate of the type of preference object.

Comment: You can just add the `filter()` statement you already have directly after the `flatMap()`or before the `collect()`.

Comment: Can you add more explanation to what your code does @SamuelPhilipp please ?

Comment: @MithunS did it. I hope I didn't miss anything.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a bit modified version of @Rohit 's answer since I also needed to make use of my guice assisted filterFactory and Predicate interfaces. But , nonetheless your answer is also pretty great.

Comment: I dont understand why my question has been down-voted. I didnt find any existing question like mine so I asked, and I repeatedly updated each time someone requested for more information.

Comment: @MithunS I did not downvote, but maybe it is a bit to specific, so it doesn't have much value for other users.